# how to draw dynamic travel path on google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps

> i have integrated google map in android. and i am getting current location using GPS. on Onlocationchanged i am updating the current location.
>
> My doubt is i am on the Google map UI . i wants to walk or drive that time from my current location as starting point and i wants to start draw the line on map dynamically.
>
> i searched on net for long time but i am not getting any solution . here is my code please anyone help me to over come this problem.

```
private void initalizeMap()
{
     // Google Play Services are available
           // Getting GoogleMap object from the fragment
            googleMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if(gps.canGetLocation())
            {
                  double latitude = Double.valueOf(Helper.loadSavedPreferences(getActivity(), NameConversion.LATITUDE));
                  double longtitude = Double.valueOf(Helper.loadSavedPreferences(getActivity(), NameConversion.LONGITUDE));

                  Log.d("getting gps value", ""+ latitude);
                  Log.d("getting gps Long", ""+ longtitude);
                // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longtitude);
                // create marker
                marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here!");
                // Changing marker icon
                // set yours icon here
                marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_green_point));
                // Showing the current location in Google Map
                googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
                // Zoom in the Google Map
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(25));
                googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "failed To get the location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location

        Log.d("latitude map Class", "latitude:  " + gps.getLatitude());
        Log.d("longitude Map CLass", "longitude:  " + gps.getLongitude());

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // create marker
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here!");
        // Changing marker icon
        // set yours icon here
        marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_green_point));
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(25));

}
```

> and i tried with following links [1 st lnikn [second link](http://john.katsiotis.com/blog/android---draw-a-path-array-of-points-in-mapview#comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the drive or walking time on Google maps you have to make use of the Direction API's provided by Google. The API call for the Direction would would something like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Chicago,IL&destination=Los%20Angeles,CA&sensor=false
```

And you can embed that inside a class where you would make an http call using AsyncTask which would look like this:

```
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
url.put("origin", origin);
url.put("destination", destination);
url.put("sensor",false);
```

Please follow this [tutorial](https://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part5) or [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/) in order get the direction API (that includes driving, transit. walking and bicycling direction on your maps. )

Hope that would help!!!

Comment: hey thanks a lot. using the 1 st link i got the solution